# Discretize value that is in range [0,1] in 10 bins

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\User\\Desktop\\20_p_n1.csv',sep=',')
#print(data)
list = data['F'].tolist()
#print(list)
pd.qcut(list,10, labels=None, retbins=False, precision=1, duplicates='drop')
```

Here I have converted dataframe to list so that I can pass it to pd.qcut().

This is what I got as output. My data contains value between [0,1] with values as 0.1,0.2,0.5, etc. But I am only able to generate one category.

```
[(-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], ..., (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0], (-0.1, 1.0]]
Length: 25192
Categories (1, interval[float64]): [(-0.1, 1.0]]
```

data.head()

```
    F
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
```

[pd.qcut output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vdi0.jpg)

[data.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFzAx.jpg)

Comment: You can use `print(data.head())` copy the data and paste it here. We don't want images.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I am having data of 25000 rows and each row contains data within range [0,1]. I want to discretize those values in 10 bins so that at the end I can perform one-hot encoding to get output in binary values.

Comment: F
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0

Comment: array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.6,  0.4,  0.9,  0.7,  1. ,  0.3,  0.5,  0.8])

Comment: @DevanshuKhokhani, i can't reproduce this behaviour. What is your Pandas and Numpy versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).

```
[In] 1: pd.cut(np.random.rand(100), 10)

[Out]1: [(0.348, 0.38], (0.156, 0.188], (0.316, 0.348], (0.348, 0.38], (0.156, 0.188], (0.059, 0.0914], (0.348, 0.38], (0.156, 0.188], (0.348, 0.38], (0.284, 0.316]]
Categories (10, object): [(0.059, 0.0914] < (0.0914, 0.124] < (0.124, 0.156] < (0.156, 0.188] ... (0.252, 0.284] < (0.284, 0.316] < (0.316, 0.348] < (0.348, 0.38]]
```

Comment: `pd.qcut(np.random.rand(100),10).categories.shape` is also 10

Comment: The categories shape should be 10 since there are 10 bins.

Comment: Funny thing is ,observe the output of the OP. This is want is bugging him. He got categories len as 1 though bin is 10

Comment: Thank you. I got the result into 10 categories. Just one more question. How can I convert it to one-hot encoding for ex: 0.1 falls in range [0,0.1] then it should show 0100000000.

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(pd.qcut(df['F'],10))`